# Windows Admin Center Powershell access denied

Tags: windows, powershell, sysadmin

I'm using the latest version of Windows Admin Center (2103) and when attempting to use the Powershell console within WAC, after supplying my credentials, the connection always fails with the following:

```
Connecting to remote server <REDACTED> failed with the following error message: Access is denied.  For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

This issue has occurred across all previous versions of WAC and irrespective of the version of Windows on the target servers.  I can successfully connect to Powershell via all manners local and remote outside of WAC, but from within it will not work.  There doesn't seem to be any useful error messages hitting the logs on the WAC server nor on the target servers.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the format of your username.
'Access is denied' will occur when using the UPN format:
**username@domain.com**

Instead, connect to the server with the SamAccountName format: **DOMAIN\username**